# Pylint does not ignore migrations

Tags: python, django, pylint, django-migrations, pre-commit.com

I use Pylint and run it via a pre-commit hook. It doesn't ignore my migrations folders. What should I add to the configuration?

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.5.2
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: system
        types: [python]
        args:
        - --rcfile=./backend/.pylintrc
        - --load-plugins=pylint_django
```

And file *.pylintrc*:

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("./backend")'
max-line-length=120
disable=
    missing-module-docstring,
    missing-function-docstring,
    missing-class-docstring,
    too-few-public-methods,
    no-self-use,
    fixme,
ignore=migrations
```

Comment: 1) A pre-commit hook in what context? 2) What is pre-commit.com?

Comment: Should the tag be `pre-commit.com`? It is not the name of the tool (it seems to be *"pre-commit"* (though an overly generic name)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, please don't retag, and please don't edit my answers again thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pre-commit [passes filenames as positional arguments](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) to hooks

this means that it is calling pylint as:

```
pylint path/to/filename.py path/to/migrations/filename.py ...
```

when you invoke pylint like this, it produces lint errors for any files on the commandline explicitly.  the `ignore` setting is only used for pylint's recursion mode

the suggested fix is to [exclude](https://pre-commit.com/#config-exclude) those files from pylint in your pre-commit configuration

note also your configuration has another problem:

- you're using the repository based configuration, but then overriding the setting with a `language: system` hook so you're discarding the repository configuration entirely

putting that all together:

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: system
        types: [python]
        exclude: ^migrations/
        args:
        - --rcfile=./backend/.pylintrc
        - --load-plugins=pylint_django
```

---

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It really make sense and should work. But I still have the same problem, maybe I should take a look on something else.

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- can you show some output?  my first guess is that you don't have a a migrations folder but instead a `something/migrations` (and so the regex pattern I used in my example won't match)

Comment: Yeah, I had problem with regex. Now it's fine, thank you!